# Proof from definition that transposing an operator two times does nothing

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

$\newcommand{\Ket}[1]{\left|#1\right>}$
$\newcommand{\Bra}[1]{\left<#1\right|}$

In "principles of quantum mechanics", a definition of the transpose of an operator was given:

\begin{equation}
\Omega \Ket{v}=\Ket{\Omega v}\implies \Bra v\Omega^\dagger=\Bra{\Omega v}
\end{equation}

The author used an orthonormal basis to prove that $\Omega^\dagger_{ij}=\Omega^*_{ji}$. It is then easy to see that $\Omega^{\dagger\dagger}=\Omega$.
How could this result be obtained without losing generality? I understand that the very design of the braket system is dedicated to an inner product space, but would it be possible to prove only by that given definition?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "without losing generality"? Do you want a more general proof of this within a mathematical context? Also, the bra-ket notation was justified because a Hilbert space forms the ambient space of Quantum Mechanics (in particular, a separable Hilbert space) and for those spaces, the so-called Riesz Theorem holds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite easy to show that $\Omega^{\dagger\dagger}=\Omega$ without referring to matrix elements:
\begin{equation}
\left< v \, | \,  \Omega w \right> = \left< \Omega^{\dagger}v \, |  \, w \right> = \left< v \, | \, \Omega^{\dagger \dagger} w \right>.
\end{equation}
From this it follows that
\begin{equation}
\left< v \, | \,  (\Omega -\Omega^{\dagger \dagger}) w \right> = 0.
\end{equation}
Choosing $v =(\Omega -\Omega^{\dagger \dagger}) w $, we get
$$
\left< (\Omega -\Omega^{\dagger \dagger}) w \, | \,  (\Omega -\Omega^{\dagger \dagger}) w \right> = 0
$$
for every vector $w$, and so by one of the properties of the inner product we conclude that $(\Omega -\Omega^{\dagger \dagger}) w=0$ or
$$\Omega w = \Omega^{\dagger \dagger}w.$$
I think this is your question, if not I'll remove this answer.

Comment: Thanks, this is good. Can you do one without using even the inner product? Also how do you type your pretty kets?

Comment: If you define the adjoint/hermitian conjugate in terms of how it acts on inner products, then that definition is the starting point in proving anything, so I think not. I actually thought your kets were nicer and tried to copy them but didn't succed :P, to see mine right click on the math -> Show Math As -> TeX Commands.

Comment: Got it, thank you very much!